# Parallel and distributed execution of multiple scenarios in taurus

Tags: jmeter, distributed, taurus

I have following requirements to execute the performance test via Taurus.
Requirements:
1. A single jmx on multiple(distributed) jmeters
2. For every Jmeter an unique IP address to be passed at run time
3. For every Jmeter a set of unique .csv path has to be provided in .yml(as data source)
4. All Jmeters should run in parallel and report should be combined of all.

Tried with following, but unable to achieve. Let me know or share the sample .yml if any one done such kind of scenario.

```
execution:

- scenario:
#    scenario1:
        script: varTest.jmx
        distributed:
            - localhost:1099
        variables:
            host: "10"
- scenario:
#    scenario2:
        script: varTest.jmx
        distributed:
            - localhost:2010
        variables:
            host: "20"
```

In this,need to override hosts dynamically with option **-o**.
It doesn't contain csv datasource details, pls share the how to create a .yml for such requirement.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
---
execution:
- distributed:
    - localhost:1099
  scenario:
    script: varTest.jmx
    distributed:
    variables:
      host: "10"
- distributed:
    - localhost:2010
    scenario:
    script: varTest.jmx
    variables:
      host: "20"
```

References:

- [Run JMeter in Distributed Mode](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-JMeter-in-Distributed-Mode)
- [Running Taurus in Command Line](https://gettaurus.org/docs/CommandLine/)
- [Taurus - Working with Multiple JMeter Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests/)